# Rails delayed_jobs don't run in a Rails context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

So I have some `delayed_job`s that are getting enqueued and dequeued properly.  The problem is that when running them, either with `$ bundle exec rake jobs:work` or `$ script/delayed_job start`, the processing code doesn't properly load a Rails context, so the jobs don't get processed properly unless I manually add the relevant `require`s to `environment.rb`.  This is neither clean nor sane, so I'd like to figure out why the runner doesn't seem to be loading the full Rails context.  This is built on the Mongoid backend - I would hope that would have nothing to do with the situation, though.  Help?

Comment: Have you tried running them like: RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start or bundle exec rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: That seemed to have no effect, but OTOH the problem seems to have mysteriously resolved itself.  Sigh.  Still hoping for some insight into what the problem might have been in case it returns...